# Change img tag src from array of images with javascript. Dice Game

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to write a simple dice game using Javascript. The code declares an array of images, and 2 img tags in html. I'm trying to change the image of img tags from the images of the array. I tried to change the img.src on the button.onclick event, but O get 2 errors: 1- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null, and the second error says that the imgArray is undefined!. Could you help me to solve this problem please? Here is my code I've written so far:

```js
window.onload = function() {

vvar imgArray = new Array(8);
   
imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'images/d1.png';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'images/d2.png';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'images/d3.png';

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'images/d4.png';

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = 'images/d5.png';

imgArray[5] = new Image();
imgArray[5].src = 'images/d6.png';

imgArray[6] = new Image();
imgArray[6].src = 'images/placeholder1.png';

imgArray[7] = new Image();
imgArray[7].src = 'images/placeholder2.png';

};

var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
var die2 = document.getElementById("die2");

 function rollDice(){
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
    die1.src = imgArray[d1-1].src;
    die2.src = imgArray[d2-1].src;
    status.innerHTML = "You rolled "+diceTotal+".";
    if(diceTotal == 7 || diceTotal == 11){
        status.innerHTML += " You Won!";
    }
 else {
  status.innerHTML = " You Lost!";
 }
}
document.getElementById("roll").onclick = rollDice;
```

```css
img.dice{
 float:left;
 width:65px;
 height: 65px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding:1px;
 font-size:24px;
 text-align:center;
 margin:5px;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>

</head>
<body>
<img id="die1" class="dice src="images/placeholder1.png" alt="dice1">
<img id="die2" class="dice src="images/placeholder2.png" alt="dice2">
<button id="roll">Roll Dice</button>
<h2 id="status" style="clear:left;"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: move `document.getElementById("roll").onclick = rollDice;` to inside the onload handler

Comment: `imgArray` is local to the scope of your "onload" function.

Comment: You need to have the entire code block within the onload handler

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ax1kd723/2/

Answer (score 0):

fix the fist line of javascript:

```
vvar imgArray = new Array(9);//error
```

and close the class attribute values in your html and [it should work](https://jsfiddle.net/w9dnguoo/13/) :

```
<img id="die1" class="dice" src="images/placeholder1.png" alt="dice1">
<img id="die2" class="dice" src="images/placeholder2.png" alt="dice2">
```